# Aggregate data in csv to 2d array with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset in csv file. Headers are 
`{user_id, movie_id, rating}` .

```
1 3 3 
1 2 2
1 1 5
2 2 1
2 3 3
1 5 4
```

I need to create a 2-D user_movie ratings array from this data. Which should be look like rows - user_id and columns - movie_id

```
X 1 2 3 4 5
1 5 2 3 0 4
2 0 1 3 0 5
```

I loaded CSV data to dataframe. Is there any straight-forward method to do this in pandas. Or should I iterate and create this 2-D array ?

I tried following code and

```
def data_preprocess(data_file):
    r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']
    user_ratings_file = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep='\t', names=r_cols)
    user_ratings_file = user_ratings_file.pivot(index='user_id', columns='movie_id', values='rating').fillna(0).astype(int).reindex(
    columns=np.arange(1, 6), fill_value=0)
    print (user_ratings_file)
    return user_ratings_file
```

I am getting

```
movie_id  1  2  3  4  5
user_id                
1 1 5     0  0  0  0  0
1 2 2     0  0  0  0  0
1 3 3     0  0  0  0  0
1 5 4     0  0  0  0  0
2 2 1     0  0  0  0  0
2 3 3     0  0  0  0  0
```

and `print (user_ratings_file.pivot(index='user_id', columns='movie_id', values='rating'))` gives me

```
   movie_id  NaN
    user_id      
    1 1 5     NaN
    1 2 2     NaN
    1 3 3     NaN
    1 5 4     NaN
    2 2 1     NaN
    2 3 3     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], 
                   'rating': [3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4], 
                   'movie_id': [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5]})

df = df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='movie_id', values='rating')
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .reindex(columns=np.arange(1,6), fill_value=0)

print (df)
movie_id  1  2  3  4  5
user_id                
1         5  2  3  0  4
2         0  1  3  0  0
```

Another solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['user_id','movie_id'])['rating']
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reindex(columns=np.arange(1,6), fill_value=0)
print (df)
movie_id  1  2  3  4  5
user_id                
1         5  2  3  0  4
2         0  1  3  0  0
```

But if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

need aggregate duplicates:

```
print (df)
   user_id  movie_id  rating
0        1         3       3
1        1         2       2
2        1         1       5
3        2         2       1
4        2         3       3 <-duplicates for 2,3
5        2         3       8 <-duplicates for 2,3
6        1         5       4

df = df.groupby(['user_id','movie_id'])['rating']
       .mean()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reindex(columns=np.arange(1,6), fill_value=0)
print (df)

movie_id    1    2    3  4    5
user_id                        
1         5.0  2.0  3.0  0  4.0
2         0.0  1.0  5.5  0  0.0
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some `aggfunc`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='movie_id', values='rating', fill_value=0, aggfunc=np.mean)
       .reindex(columns=np.arange(1,6), fill_value=0)
print (df)
movie_id  1  2    3  4  5
user_id                  
1         5  2  3.0  0  4
2         0  1  5.5  0  0
```

Comment: I am getting different results. I have added my results and tried code at the end to the question

Comment: Gives

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
user_id     6 non-null object
movie_id    0 non-null float64
rating      0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 216.0+ bytes
None

Comment: I add sample dataframe to my answer, how doeas it works? also what return `print (user_ratings_file.pivot(index='user_id', columns='movie_id', values='rating'))` ?

Comment: Hard coded data frame worked fine. And the out put my original pivot print is `movie_id  NaN
  user_id      
1 1 5     NaN
1 2 2     NaN
1 3 3     NaN
1 5 4     NaN
2 2 1     NaN
2 3 3     NaN`

Comment: Can you add this sample to question? because problematic formating of commnents. thanks. Also is in real data separator `tab` ?

Comment: added it to the question body

Comment: Thanks. I think problem with data is there is no `tab` separator, but `whitespace`. so try change `sep='\t'` to `sep="\s+"`